# UI Drawer in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

**Please, how do I call the "UI Drawer"?** (or whatever it's called)

IMAGE:

[image]

I basically want to do the same exact thing as in the Contacts app when choosing a photo for a contact and I do **NOT** want any buttons on the main interface. I want to call the "UI drawer" to Take a picture, choose one from the library, edit or delete **(EXACTLY like adding a photo in the Contacts app)**.

**Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `UIActionSheet`. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)